# How to get pointer on array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, pointers

I have such an array:

```
    const char arg_arr[][100] = {
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
    };
```

and then I have such a method `ParseCmdLine(const char *argv[]);`

So, in order to pass my `arg_arr` I need to get pointer to it.

I try to invoke this method such way `ParseCmdLine(*arg_arr)` or like this `ParseCmdLine(&arg_arr)`, but it doesn't work.

Question is - how to pass this arr as a pointer?

Comment: The types `const char arg_arr[][100]` and `const char *argv[]` are incompatible. You can't convert the former to the latter; you need to rewrite the former.

Comment: `const char arg_arr[][100]` and `const char *argv[]` differ. `char [][100]` is an array of arrays of 100 chars. `const char *argv[]` is an array of _pointers_ to const char.

Comment: try `void ParseCmdLine(const char (*argv)[100]) {}`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica but how to do it? Or there is no way to pass these params?

Comment: @KamilCuk but how to do it? Or there is no way to pass these params?

Comment: @Waqar I can not change method signature

Comment: Can you change the array?

Comment: @Waqar yes, it is my code

Comment: You made a 5x100 matrix, not a conditional array. The issue here is that you're not calling the column data.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:c] and [tag:c++]. The solution is different for either programming language. Please choose either one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
 const char arg_arr[][100] = {
 ...
};
```

To:

```
 const char *arg_arr[] = {
 ...
};
```

Comment: Not forcing anything, just what was in the question. Copy pasta

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko: note that `ParseCmdLine` must have a way to tell how many elements are present in the array. Either pass this count as an extra argument (`argc`) or add a trailing `NULL` pointer after the last string, or both as is done for the arguments of the `main()` function.

Answer (score 2):

`arg_arr` is a constant array of arrays of `char`, which is a different type from what `ParseCmdLine` expects: a pointer to an array of pointers to constant `char` arrays.

You should define `arg_arr` this way:

```
const char *arg_arr[] = {
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
    NULL
};
```

and pass it directly as `ParseCmdLine(arg_arr)`.

Note that `ParseCmdLine` must have a way to tell how many elements are present in the array. Either pass this count as an extra argument (`argc`) or add a trailing `NULL` pointer after the last string as shown above, or both as is done for the arguments of the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get pointer on array?

Available options regarding what you have provided ( without changing your code ):

**Numerically:**

[image]

**Alphabetically:**

[image]

[Here's](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/145803/) a guide that I think might help.

Answer (score -3):

**The name of the array is essentially the address of its first element**.